# Why is a holomorphic map from $C$ to the upper half plane $H$ bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Recently I met the following result:

A holomorphic map from $\mathbb{C}$ to a compact Riemann surface $M$ is a constant map.

The proof is given as follows:

Suppose  a holomorphic map $f:\mathbb{C}\to M$, since $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected and $\pi: \mathbb{H}\to M$ is a universal covering, there is a lift $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{H}.$  By Liouville Theorem, $\tilde{f}$ is constant. So is $f$.

Why is $\tilde{f}$  bounded? I am confused about this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27271/42969

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove directly that $\tilde{f}$ is  bounded. But it is a constant because $e^{i\tilde{f}}$ is bounded. Aplly Liouville's Thereom to  this function.

Comment: I see，it follows by $|e^{i\tilde{f}}|\leq 1.$